# Is this a valid link-only answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, link-only-answers

So I flagged following answer as "Link-only answer", as ... well... see for yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35296737/3046513

According to the flag reviewers my flag got disputed, which means either me or the reviewers have a misunderstanding on what a valid answer is.

Can somebody please clarify if that is a valid answer? If so I have been rising tons of "invalid" flags based on me misunderstanding that a link only answer is invalid.

In my eyes that is clearly a "link-only" answer and need to be edited.

Comment: Err, how are you flagging it as "link-only answer"? Which flag reason is that? Are you raising a custom moderator flag?

Comment: If you're wondering whether or not you're flagging things appropriately, my bigger question is about how come that **question** didn't have any close votes before you opened this meta question.

Comment: "see for yourself" Other users can't see your flags. You flagged this as "not an answer".

Comment: I'd say its a VLQ answer to a VLQ question.

Comment: Sadly it takes [more votes to delete than to dispute](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11192437) and too many reviewers think that links that answer a question are fine

Comment: I see, thanks to clear things up to me :)

Comment: Feel free to stop on by the [SOCVR](http://stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room if you are ever in doubt. And especially after another 50 rep when we could really use you. Shameless plug.

Comment: No such thing as a *valid* link only answer, link only answers by definition are invalid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to BoltClock, you flagged this as "not an answer." The description for the ["not an answer" flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer) states:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

I will agree with you that this is a ***bad*** answer, but it *is* an answer. At least, it meets those criteria: it makes an attempt to answer the question.

Neither is it "link-only"; the answer contains other words in addition to the link, such that even if the link were to go dead, it would *still* be an answer. He literally could have posted:

> Look into Animations with react native.

and that would be *an answer*. It'd be an even crappier one, but it would still be an answer—albeit a downvote-worthy one.

You can flag these if you want, and I understand the compulsion to do so, but you are taking a risk that the community will disagree with (dispute) your flag. They are right to do so—there is a convincing argument to be made that answers like this are, in fact, answers.

What you should be doing instead is focusing on the *low-quality questions* that lead to answers like this. [This very question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296168/how-to-drag-an-item-react-native) is a good example. There are at least 3 reasons why this question is not a good, on-topic question for Stack Overflow—not the least of which is that it produces these types of low-quality, link-mostly answers. If you take care of the questions, the answers solve themselves. Closed questions can't be answered, and closure is the first step to deletion.

Comment: I see, I also should have flagged the question for beeing low quality then, thanks for clearing stuff up :)

Comment: Well, no. You should have flagged it as needing to be closed. Or, with about 50 more reputation points to your account, voted to close it yourself. @ronon

Answer (score 8):

That looks like an attempt to answer a bad question. Don't flag for moderators to deal with the answers to bad questions, because moderators and reviewers often won't notice the real problem when processing these flags. When the question is at fault for bad answers, deal with the source of the problem by voting to close the question (and later delete it if it isn't improved).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know enough about JavaScript to say for sure whether or not this is valid answer or not.  I don't know how big of a clue-in the first sentence of the answer would be.

To be clear though, there is no such thing as a "valid" "link-only" answer.  If an answer is only a link, the answer is not valid ("not an answer") because if the link rots, the answer has lost 100% of its value.

If the link in this answer died, the answer effectively becomes this:

> Look into Animations with react native.

This is roughly what we must judge the answer on.  But sometimes the actual text for the link on the Stack Overflow side provides clues that stick even if the link dies.  For example, the answer could have been written as this:

> Look into Animations with react native. Check out this article: [Animated Drag and Drop with React Native](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317269/2792531).

I've simulated the link-rot by making the link simply point back here.  Is the above quote block an answer (considering there's no content of any value behind the link)?  It's not a great one, but it is an answer.